# Simple regular expression substitution

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to take all instances of '.UpdateText("Text here");' and turn it into '.Text = "Text here";'

I've combed over regular expression sites but I can't seem to find something so simple...  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Oh well it's the regular expression parser in Visual Studio 2008...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact right answer depends on which tool is used.

Here's an example with sed:

```
sed 's,\.UpdateText(\([^)]*\));,.Text = \1;,'
```

The regular expression, if supported by the tool evaluating it, may be one of these:

```
.*UpdateText(\([^)]*\)).*
.*UpdateText\(([^)]*)\).*
```

Not all regular-expression tools support "capture groups".  And, there is a variation between such tools both in syntax for identifying the group, and for using it in the output.

For Visual Studio 2008 Find and Replace (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ewy2t5e0.aspx), this should do the trick:

```
Find:    \.UpdateText(\([^)]*\));
Replace: .Text = $1
```

According this this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.90%29.aspx:

> There are many syntax differences between the regular expressions that
>   can be used in Find what and Replace with and those that are valid in
>   .NET Framework programming. For example, in the Find and Replace
>   window, braces {} are used for tagging expressions to be replaced: to
>   change every occurrence of doesn't to does not, you would use the find
>   expression {does}n't and the replace expression \1 not .

So, this works for me in Visual Studio 2012:

```
Find:    \.UpdateText\(([^)]*)\)
Replace: .Text = $1
```

Comment: It does find the .UpdateText correctly but it replaces it with .Text = $1

Comment: Darn. That's what that page shows.  I do not have Visual Studio 2008 to try it myself, but I might be able to try on someone elses machine.  Can you tell me how the find and replace are executed?

Comment: I don't understand, what are you looking for?  I tried executing that find and replace and it replaced .UpdateText("text"); with .Text = $1

Comment: I'm looking for step-by-step instructions on getting to the Find + Replace function in VS2008.  For example, Edit -> Find & Replace (I suspect this is incorrect).

Comment: Oh yeah it's in Edit->'Find and replace in files' or 'quick replace'

Comment: Can you try the `{...}` and '\1` variation and let me know?  I'm still trying to get access to VS 2008.

Comment: It should be the same parser as 2010 as far as I know and the express version is free.  I tried the updated Find: \.UpdateText({[^)]*}); and it didn't find anything

Comment: I tried this syntax with success `UpdateText\(([^)]*)\)` and `.Text = $1`, after making sure to click the "Use Regular Expressions" under find options.

Comment: Sorry that I did not try the full example; I didn't have it in front of me at the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
Find:      \.UpdateText\({:q}\);
Replace:   .Text = \1;
```

Note how parentheses need to be escaped in find. ':q' is quoted string in VS regex.